# semaphore between two processes doesn't work using fork

Tags: c

trying to create semaphore rutine between two processes but code seems to break too early. Tried to compare with other students who succeeded and our codes looks almost the same except that my i do fork only after semget and semctl.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t n;
    int semid;
    int key = 98757;
    short sarray[1] = {2};
    struct sembuf sops[1];
    int err;

    semid = semget(key, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (semid == -1)
    {
        perror("semid failed");
        return 0;
    }

    err = semctl(semid, 1, SETALL, sarray);
    if (err == -1);/*code beakes down here*/
    {
        perror("semctl failed");

        return 0;
    }

    n = fork();

    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("n < 0");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n==0)/*child*/
    {
        sops[0].sem_num = 0;
        sops[0].sem_op = 0;
        sops[0].sem_flg = 0;
        err = semop(semid, sops, 1);
        if (err < 0)
        {
            printf("debugging semid < 0");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("%d", n);
        exit(0);
    }
    else/*parent*/
    {
        sleep(3);
        sops[0].sem_num = 0;
        sops[0].sem_op = -1;
        sops[0].sem_flg = 0;
        err = semop(semid, sops, 1);
        if (err < 0)
        {
            printf("debugging semid < 0");
            return 0;
        }
        wait(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you test `err` after calling `semctl`, there is an error in the `if` statement. The cause is hard to see and obscured my a comment that sits too close to the code.

Here is the test without that comment:

```
if (err == -1);
{
    perror("semctl failed");

    return 0;
}
```

The semicolon after the condition makes this an `if` with an empty body: The check is performed, but nothing is done.

The code block in curly braces is entered unconditionally, regardless of the value of `err`. Such blocks are legal and sometimes useful to structure your code and to define tightly scoped variables.

**TL;DR**: Remove the semicolon:

```
if (err == -1) {
    perror("semctl failed");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A decent compiler should warn you about that. For example, using clang on osx I get `warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]
        if (0);
              ^`
(with some more useful info, all more nicely formatted than I can reproduce in this comment!)